# How to obtain a 2d transformation matrix from two pairs of points?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, linear-algebra, affinetransform

OpenCV provides:

- `getRotationMatrix2D` to get a 2x3 transformation matrix (rotation, scale, shift) defined by `center`, `angle` and `scale`
- `getAffineTransform` to get a 2x3 transformation matrix (rotation, scale, shift, sheer) defined by three pairs of points.

I'd like to get a transformation matrix with rotation, scale, and shift (i.e. no sheer) from two pairs of points.

Here is my current implementation, which works, but it's way too complex for my taste:

```py
from typing import Tuple, List

import cv2
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing


def _third_triangle_point(p1: Tuple[float, float], p2: Tuple[float, float]) -> Tuple[float, float]:
    """Calculate the third point of an isosceles right-angled triangle."""
    p1_arr = np.array(p1, dtype=np.float32)
    p2_arr = np.array(p2, dtype=np.float32)
    diff = p2_arr - p1_arr
    perpendicular = np.array((diff[1], -diff[0]), dtype=np.float32)
    result = p1_arr + perpendicular
    return result[0], result[1]


def _stack_points(points: List[Tuple[float, float]]) -> np.typing.NDArray[np.float32]:
    return np.vstack([np.array(p, dtype=np.float32) for p in points])


def get_transformation_between_two_point_pairs(
        src: Tuple[Tuple[float, float], Tuple[float, float]],
        dst: Tuple[Tuple[float, float], Tuple[float, float]]
) -> np.typing.NDArray[np.float32]:
    # cv2.getAffineTransform takes three point pairs.
    # It supports rotation, translation, scaling, and shearing.
    # We don't need the shearing,
    # so we invent a third point with a stable relation to the given two.
    return cv2.getAffineTransform(  # type: ignore
        _stack_points([src[0], src[1], _third_triangle_point(src[0], src[1])]),
        _stack_points([dst[0], dst[1], _third_triangle_point(dst[0], dst[1])])
    )


print(get_transformation_between_two_point_pairs(((10, 10), (17, 23)), ((30, 30), (70, 30))))
```

```
[[ 1.28440367  2.3853211  -6.69724771]
 [-2.3853211   1.28440367 41.00917431]]
```

Is there a simpler way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Opencv has an estimateRigidTransform function which lets you choose between 6 dof (3 point pairs) and 4 dof (2 point pairs). Give it a try.

Comment: @Micka Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. :) According to the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.9.0/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga762cbe5efd52cf078950196f3c616d48), `estimateRigidTransform` is deprecated in favor of `estimateAffinePartial2D`. Would you like to post your solution as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: please after trying it write your own answer (and accept it). I don't have working code snipped at hand, which might be useful for someone finding this question. The info about estimateAffinePartial2D is very helpful for me, too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simple, one can just use `estimateAffinePartial2D`:

```py
from typing import Tuple

import cv2
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing


def get_transformation_between_two_point_pairs(
        src: Tuple[Tuple[float, float], Tuple[float, float]],
        dst: Tuple[Tuple[float, float], Tuple[float, float]]
) -> np.typing.NDArray[np.float32]:
    return cv2.estimateAffinePartial2D(np.array([src[0], src[1]]), np.array([dst[0], dst[1]]))[0]  # type: ignore


print(get_transformation_between_two_point_pairs(((10, 10), (17, 23)), ((30, 30), (70, 30))))
```

```
[[ 1.28440367  2.3853211  -6.69724771]
 [-2.3853211   1.28440367 41.00917431]]
```